# Find 3rd Parent div up for each div with class, then add css to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

SO for each div with ".protected_wrap" class I am needed to go up 3 levels, then add a class or css to that div.

my code

```
$( "div.protected_wrap" ).parents().eq(2).className( "hidephotos" )

$( "div.protected_wrap" ).parents().eq(2).css( "display", "none" );
```

the 3rd div up is ".photo_item_wrap" but nothing is being done as far as adding css or a class.

seems nothing is happening though

Comment: Can you post a sample of the html you're working with as well please?

Comment: The function is called addClass, not className.  https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: A good way to debug is to add `debugger;` then in the inspector walk through an elements properties to find the path to it's parents.

Comment: Without seeing your HTML, we can't confirm that "3rd div up" really is ".photo_item_wrap" and not the 2nd or 4th div - or maybe it's just that you're using `.className()` instead of `.addClass()` (try `.hide()`) - or that your css for `.hidephotos` doesn't actually hide anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

It gets the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

This should do the trick:

```
$( "div.protected_wrap" ).closest('.photo_item_wrap').css( "display", "none" );
```

You could also use [.parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) like you're doing but you need to specify the selector like this

```
$( "div.protected_wrap" ).parents('.photo_item_wrap').css( "display", "none" );
```

The thing is with `.parents();` it will find **all** the ancestors with the specified selector. So if you have multiple parent elements with that selector, I suggest you use `.closest()`

**Side notes**

1. You can use `.hide()` instead of `.css("display", "none")`
2. To add a class to an element, use [.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers, yeah I meant to do addClass but lack of sleep and all.